# Unable to get ActionBar on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.rayz.digitalpostbox.R;
import com.rayz.digitalpostbox.activities.HomeActivity;
import com.rayz.digitalpostbox.adapters.TabsPagerAdapter;


public class AccountAndCardTabFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = {"Accounts", "Cards"};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_and_cards_tab_layout, container, false);
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("My Wallet");
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).refferToolbar();
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).toolbarFunction();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("Dashboard");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Layout file is as :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

My problem is that i am using action bar on Fragment as require in app
and it gives null pointer exception on 
 actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
Below code is working fine in simple activity aclss but it is not work in fragment. Please suggest.

below is stackof errar

```
06-30 16:57:53.156 5715-5715/com.rayz.digitalpostbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.rayz.digitalpostbox, PID: 5715
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.rayz.digitalpostbox.fragments.AccountAndCardTabFragment.onCreateView(AccountAndCardTabFragment.java:35)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
06-30 16:57:54.508 5715-5715/com.rayz.digitalpostbox I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5715 SIG: 9
```

Comment: try `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: @TimCastelijns  I have already tried but it is not working

Comment: does your activity have ActionBar at a time you are trying to get it in fragment?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActionBarActivity then try below code

```
actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

and if AppCompatActivity then

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```